I have a text appearing above all my layout file (laravel)
Please I have a text appearing on top of my page before my layout files independent of the one I choose. When I view page source in chrome, it shows like this
0 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">.....

I am unable to find where this 0 comes from, i must have accidentally typed it when browsing through laravel files somehow.
If I just type xyz at the beginning of my layout file i get this:
0 xyz
<!DOCTYPE html>

So the previous 0 is being rendered before the layout file.
I need it gone....
I have tried changing Layout files but it still persists above the layout files.
I have gone through my layouts and components and cannot find where this is coming from.
I have used file search but, looking through 0 in all files doesn't seem possible.
If I could understand how laravel render its pages, I could find what comes before the layout file and I could try to find a solution from there. its giving me big concerns.
New project
was trying to change the layout files when this happened
LIVEWIRE COMPONENT
<?php
    
    namespace App\Livewire;
    
    use Livewire\Attributes\Layout;
    use Livewire\Attributes\Title;
    use Livewire\Component;
    
    #[Layout('layouts.guest')]
    #[Title('GMH - Home')]
    class HomePage extends Component
    {
        public function render()
        {
            return view('livewire.home-page');
        }
    }

PAGE INSPECT
0 xyz
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">....

GUEST BLADE LAYOUT
xyz
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="{{ str_replace('_', '-', app()->getLocale()) }}">
        <head>
            <meta charset="utf-8">.....

Laravel 11
Livewire 3

Search your project for any echo statements

That or you can checkout to your previous commits until you can no longer see the 0. Once you figure that out, the last commit where 0 is displayed is the probable culprit. Fix that, stash, then checkout to your latest. pop and then test.

I have everything suggested, the 0 actually comes before the layout is rendered. If i create a new layout with artisan command, and add an empty component i only see the 0 on a white page

throw an error in place of xyz an then look at the stack trace in error handling page.
also yo can search for echo or print function in your project.

errors dont show anything about it, the only show about the type of error.
